# Not able to install opencv in my docker container due to fetching errors

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, installation, dockerfile, containers

While I am trying to install opencv through a docker file using 
`RUN add-apt-repository ppa:lkoppel/opencv`
But it is giving errors:-

1. connection refused [ip: 91.189.88.149.80]
2. unable to fetch
3. Error reading from server. remote end closed connection [ip: 91.189.88.149.80]

Due to this the required packages are not getting fetched and install

This is the docker file

```
#getting base image
FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER siddharth bhurat <bhuratsidhu@gmail.com>


RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:lkoppel/opencv

RUN apt install -y libopencv-calib3d3.2 libopencv-core3.2 libopencv-features2d3.2  libopencv-flann3.2 libopencv-highgui3.2 libopencv-imgcodecs3.2 libopencv-imgproc3.2 libopencv-ml3.2 libopencv-objdetect3.2 libopencv-photo3.2 libopencv-shape3.2 libopencv-stitching3.2 libopencv-superres3.2 libopencv-video3.2 libopencv-videoio3.2 libopencv-videostab3.2 libopencv-viz3.2 libopencv3.2-jni libopencv3.2-java libopencv-contrib3.2 

RUN apt install -y libopencv-calib3d-dev libopencv-core-dev libopencv-features2d-dev  libopencv-flann-dev libopencv-highgui-dev libopencv-imgcodecs-dev libopencv-imgproc-dev libopencv-ml-dev libopencv-objdetect-dev libopencv-photo-dev libopencv-shape-dev libopencv-stitching-dev libopencv-superres-dev libopencv-video-dev libopencv-videoio-dev libopencv-videostab-dev libopencv-viz-dev libopencv-contrib-dev libopencv-dev
```

can someone please help me

Comment: Are you sure your container has interent acces?